# How to remove storage folder from .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore file contains one big line:

```
/node_modules/public/hot/public/storage/storage/*.key/vendor/.idea/.vagrantHomestead.jsonHomestead.yamlnpm-debug.logyarn-error.log.env
```

Since I have a folder in my storage which contains all icons/images that are used in my website, I want that folder to be uploaded to github as well. Sadly it seems the whole public/storage folder is in gitignore so it's getting ignored.

Little side question - why does my gitignore file has a blank file name when looking at it in the root folder?

Comment: Are you sure that’s all one line? It looks like multiple files, which would need to each be on their own line.

Comment: Sadly it is only one line. I haven't used .gitignore before so I have no clue why are they on 1 line. This .gitignore was automatically generated with my Laravel project.

Comment: It’s possible the file has line endings different from what your editor is expecting. Try switching your editor’s line-ending mode between Unix (LF) and Windows (CR LF). See also [how to configure Git to automatically change line endings for checked-out files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

I think your `.gitignore` file is not correct then you should have one entry per line.

It looks a bit that you don't have the new line character in your file. If you need that folder in your project then remove that line from your file and add the folder.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: So ever /entry should be on  a new line? How can I know whether /public/storage/storage should be split into /public/storage and /storage or /public, /storage and /storage?

Answer (score 1):

> So ever /entry should be on a new line?

Yes.

> How can I know whether /public/storage/storage should be split into /public/storage and /storage or /public, /storage and /storage?

Each entry is relative to where the `.gitignore` is in the repo.
A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "`/*.c`" matches "`cat-file.c`" but not "`mozilla-sha1/sha1.c`" (again, relative to where the `.gitignore` is).

In order to check if your `.gitignore` does work, check the output of:

```
git check-ignore -v -- a/file/in/the/repo
```